# ProtonMail SMTP Bridge Authentication Failed

Tags: c#, smtpclient

Trying to send emails using SMTP via ProtonMail Bridge (https://protonmail.com/bridge). It basically acts as a local SMTP server for sending secure email.

When trying to send via my .Net application, Im getting:

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Authentication failed.
>   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
>   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection()
>   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
>   at EmailTest.Form1.sendButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\VisualStudio\EmailTest\EmailTest\Form1.cs:line 68

Heres my test code:

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("<my username>", "<ProtonMail bridge password>");
smtp.Host = "127.0.0.1";
smtp.Port = 1025;
smtp.Send("me@FakeEmail.com", "them@FakeEmail.com", "Test Message Subject", "Test Message Body");
```

I will also get the same exception when trying

```
smtp.EnableSsl=true
```

When I take the exact credentials/configuration and put them into an email client (Outlook or alike) it works fine.

Has anyone encountered this issue before? Is there any type of workaround for this?

The only thing I can find when searching online is to make sure UseDefaultCredentials=false is set BEFORE setting the Credentials property. But Im already doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to ProtonMail support, this is a known compatibility issue and currently has no direct resolution.

I ended up switching from System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient to [MailKit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MailKit/). It has all the same functionality and it works with the ProtonMail Smtp service

Comment: Hey man, thanks for this. I was about to give up on ProtonMail all together until I read this post. MailKit did the trick.